# Encrypting with DES and password

Tags: java, cryptography, des, encryption

I'm using the code I've found [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/PassKey.html) to encrypt using DES. I'm sending this value to 3rd party servce, but doesn't seem to work.

Question in code given code, salt and iteration are used as parameters to create initialize the cipher with the parameter spec:

```
// Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec( salt, iterationCount );

// Create the ciphers
ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key , paramSpec);
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key , paramSpec);
```

If I change the iteration count, I have different results.

How can I know what is being used in the other side of the wire? The only thing I know from this third party service, is, the algorithm to use is DES and of course the secret password.

What am I missing?

Comment: FWIW, DES is insecure, and should not be used in situations where you expect anybody to seriously attack your ciphers.  If it's the most secure way to communicate with a given service, well, let's hope you aren't interesting to anybody with a lot of computing power.

Comment: @David. Thanks for the comment. Yeap, we are aware of this. This will be used in the LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DES" itself is just a single iteration. Its successor, "Triple DES" <del>encrypts each data block three times</del> performs three iterations of the algorithm. If you are expected to perform encryption using just "DES", one iteration should be correct.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES

In general, it is considered bad practice to write your own cryptographic functions for anything other than toy implementations. Writing secure, correct libraries for cryptography can sometimes be tricky. Consider using the [Java Cryptography Architecture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html), part of the Java Platform SE 6.

Comment: what about the salt? As for the functions, the code I pointed use JCA.

Comment: Triple DES technically doesn't encrypt three times. It applies the DES algorithm 3 times to encrypt a block by encrypting, decrypting and then encrypting again.

Comment: @Joel What about the salt? What should we use?

Comment: @Joel Serves me right for writing about the algorithm having never read it myself. Thanks!

Comment: The salt should be given to you if one is used. If no salt is given, you can try not using a salt (empty string). If this system is intended to be secure, a salt (or instructions on how to generate the salt) should absolutely be given to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you know the encryption algorithm (DES) but not the key generation algorithm. For deriving a key from a password there are a lot of possibilities. The PBEParameterSpec from your example uses the PKCS#5 algorithm for deriving the key from the password. This is a very good algorithm for that purpose but often people try to develop a simple algorithm themselves - e.g. just hashing the password or some even worse methods. 
Detecting what method is used is not easy. If you have a working app using that 3rd party service yon can try to reverse engineer it to see how it works.